# Heritability estimate in LD Score Regression (LDSC)

Tags: statistics

I am trying to replicate the heritability estimates based on the [insomnia GWAS](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35835914/) summary statistics using [LDSC](https://github.com/bulik/ldsc). However, I have encountered a problem as my estimates seem to be only about half of the original estimates listed in [Table S1](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1038%2Fs41588-022-01124-w/MediaObjects/41588_2022_1124_MOESM5_ESM.xlsx). Despite my efforts to locate the error, I have been unsuccessful in finding the source of the problem.
[image]

Below are the commands I used for female estimates.

```
zcat insomnia_female_ukb2b_EUR_sumstats_20190311_with_chrX_mac_100.txt.gz |cut -f 6,11,12,15,16,17 -d $'\t'|sed  "1s/STAT/Z/" > female_useful.txt
../munge_sumstats.py --sumstats  female_useful.txt --N-col NMISS --snp RSID_UKB   --a1 A1_UKB  --a2 A2_UKB --out female_insomnia_GWAS_2022 --merge-alleles LDSCORE_w_hm3.snplist --chunksize 500000
../ldsc.py --h2 female_insomnia_GWAS_2022.sumstats.gz --ref-ld-chr eur_w_ld_chr/ --w-ld-chr eur_w_ld_chr/ --out merged_GWAS_results_h2
```

The GWAS summary statistics were downloaded from

https://ctg.cncr.nl/documents/p1651/insomnia_female_ukb2b_EUR_sumstats_20190311_with_chrX_mac_100.txt.gz

Can anyone tell me where am I wrong? Thanks.